# Extract minor version from kernel to bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cut

I am new to bash and writing a script that needs to compare the minor version of the kernel to see if it is greater than or equal to 10, and exit if it is not. Currently I have something like this:

```
KERNEL=$(uname -r)
declare -i MINOR_VERSION=$(echo $KERNEL | cut -c 3-4)
if [ "10" -gt "$MINOR_VERSION"]; then exit 0; fi
```

This is bad code, and doesn't work if the minor version is < 10 since I am using cut and depending on it being two digits. What I probably need is something that parses the minor version by using the dots.
Example:

```
$ uname -r
3.4.0-60-generic
$ MNR_VAR=<awesome bash code, with cut or sed or something>
$ echo $MNR_VAR
4
```

I have been reading `cut` and `sed` documentation but have just been slow picking it up. I would appreciate the help!

TL;DR - looking for a bash command that will extract an `int` surrounded by the first two dots in a variable. "3.13.0.x" returns '13', "3.2.0.x" returns '2', etc.

EDIT:
Some answers as one liners below for those curious.

```
uname -r | cut -d '.' -f2

uname -r | awk -F . '{print $2}'

kernel="$(uname -r)" | tmp="${kernel#*.}" | minor="${tmp%%.*}" | echo "$minor"
```

Comment: `KERNEL = $(uname -r)` is incorrect; you can't have spaces around the `=`. Also, you're eventually going to want to pay attention to the major number as well; 3.9 is too old, but 4.1 presumably isn't.

Comment: Thanks the spaces may be an autocorrect from an evil note program. And I appreciate the comment on the major version, I had already considered it and will certainly be checking that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `-c` to `cut`. Don't do that.

Use the `-f` and `-d` flags instead to control the delimiter and fields to output.

Or use `awk -F . '{print $2}' <<< "$(uname -r)"`.

Or use `IFS=. read -r _ minor _rest <<< "$(uname -r)"; echo "$minor"` (which has the benefit of not using any external utilities).

The usage of `<<< "$(uname -r)"` is bash-specific (I believe) but avoids the need for a pipe (`|`) and the sub-shell that it involves.

Comment: cool thanks! `MNR_VAR=$(echo $KERNEL | cut -d '.' -f2)` works great and is similar to where I was. Your awk answer is probably what I will use, works great and is a nice one liner. I really appreciate the help, this helps some of the documentation make more sense too.

Answer (score 4):

**In pure bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash
ker="$(uname -r)"
minker="${ker#*.}"
minker="${minker%%.*}"
echo "$minker"
```

`"${ker#*.}"` is the string after the first match of a `.` in `$ker`. Thus
`$minker` becomes `13.0-generic...` from `3.13.0-generic...`

`"${minker%%.*}"` is the string left by cutting all matches (from right) of `.` and whatever after it, in `$minker`. Thus `$minker` becomes `13` from `13.0-generic...`

[See the Bash Parameter Expansion Manual for more info](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

**Using Bash Regex:**

```
#!/bin/bash
regex='([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)'
[[ $(uname -r) =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Comment: This is sweet, and I have seen this notation before but it's not the most readable on first glance. Can you explain it a bit further or point me in a direction of something to read? Thanks!

Comment: I found [this guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) which helped a lot to understand the first answer.

Comment: @jdfLemon added a little explanation and a new method

Comment: Thanks for the extra explainer! @Jahid

Answer (score -1):

Extracting just minor version & comparing it with something is risky, because major number can change too...

I normally prefer padding the numbers with zeros, so that they can be easily compared using simple string compare.

```
kernel_version=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/0000\1/g; s/0*([0-9]{4})/\1/g') # gives 0003.0004.0000-0060-generic
if [[ "$kernel_version" < "0003.0010" ]]; then exit 0; fi
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please leave a comment. IMO, this method is more reliable than comparing just the minor version, which the other answers suggest.